# Rails : trying to pass Id from controller to view

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i'm a little noob in ruby..

i want to pass id of object that i just created to view that it will get render via render method

this is my code below

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @object.save
    format.html { render "finished_reg",param: @object.id ,notice: 'object was successfully created.' }

  #end
```

in the view

```
<%= link_to 'Here' ,"/controller/#{:param}" %>
```

but nothing happen.. how to make that and how can i print this on the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@instance_variables` persist when going from controller to views. So you can simply do:

```
<%= link_to 'Here' ,"/controller/#{@object.id}" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

As nicooga said, all instances variables (the ones that you define with @ on your controller) are available on your view and so his code will work. However, in Rails, there's even an easier way to do it: path and url helpers:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers

So your code would look like:

```
<%= link_to 'Here' ,object_path(@object) %>
```

Comment: actually that's the standard way to do it in Rails, so not really a "trick" :)